# Spring Boot WebFlux with RouterFunction log request and response body

Tags: spring-boot, routes, spring-webflux

I'm trying to log request and response body of every call received by my microservice which is using reactive WebFlux with routing function defined as bellow:

```
@Configuration
public class FluxRouter {

    @Autowired
    LoggingHandlerFilterFunction loggingHandlerFilterFunction;

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes(FluxHandler fluxHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions
                .route(POST("/post-flux").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), fluxHandler::testFlux)
                .filter(loggingHandlerFilterFunction);
    }
}


@Component
public class FluxHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FluxHandler.class);

    @LogExecutionTime(ActionType.APP_LOGIC)
    public Mono<ServerResponse> testFlux(ServerRequest request) {

        logger.info("FluxHandler.testFlux");
        
        return request
                .bodyToMono(TestBody.class)
                .doOnNext(body -> logger.info("FluxHandler-2: "+ body.getName()))
                .flatMap(testBody -> ServerResponse.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue("Hello, ")));
    }
}
```

and a router filter defined like this:

```
@Component
public class LoggingHandlerFilterFunction implements HandlerFilterFunction<ServerResponse, ServerResponse> {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingHandlerFilterFunction.class);

    @Override
    public Mono<ServerResponse> filter(ServerRequest request, HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> handlerFunction) {

        logger.info("Inside LoggingHandlerFilterFunction");

        return request.bodyToMono(Object.class)
                .doOnNext(o -> logger.info("Request body: "+ o.toString()))
                .flatMap(testBody -> handlerFunction.handle(request))
                .doOnNext(serverResponse -> logger.info("Response body: "+ serverResponse.toString()));
    }
}
```

Console logs here are:

```
Inside LoggingHandlerFilterFunction
LoggingHandlerFilterFunction-1: {name=Name, surname=Surname}
FluxHandler.testFlux
```

As you can see I'm able to log the request but after doing it the body inside the FluxHandler seems empty because this is not triggered **.doOnNext(body -> logger.info("FluxHandler-2: "+ body.getName())** and also no response body is produced. Can someone show me how to fix this or is there any other way to log request/response body when using routes in webflux?